# Automatically set combo box value when textbox contains text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox

**Overview**

I have 3 text boxes, `txt_Mobile`, `txt_Landline`, `txt_Other`. If 1 of these 3 text boxes contains a value, I need to automatically set my combo box (`cmb_PrefconNumber`) with the string "Mobile", "landline" or "other", depending on the text box that is filled. This then needs to automatically set the value of the `combobox` to the corresponding value. 
If more than two text boxes are filled, I need to let the user select it themselves. However, I still need to populate it with the given values.

I'm not sure whether I have to bind the textbox or not, as I'm not actually using the value, just the corresponding string. I've tried binding the text box in my constructor like so:

```
binding = new Binding("Text", cmb_PrefConNumber, "Text");
cmb_PrefConNumber.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

I currently have this on each `validating event handler`

```
if (!cmb_PrefConNumber.Items.Contains("Alternative"))
{
    cmb_PrefConNumber.Items.Add("Alternative");
    return;
}
```

However, these don't update my combo box, as I think it needs the two values, `int` and `string` with binding. I'm unsure of how to do this when I'm not using the textbox value itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `TextChanged` event on all 3 textboxes and start a function like `PopulateCombo(textboxID)` inside them. For textboxID you set 1, 2 and 3 for 3 different textboxes and it would look like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        PopulateCombo(1);
    }
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
    {
        PopulateCombo(2);
    }
}

private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
    {
        PopulateCombo(3);
    }
}

private void PopulateCombo(int textBoxID)
    {
        //With this you will get how many textBoxes have value
        int filledTextboxes = 0;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            filledTextboxes++;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            filledTextboxes++;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
        {
            filledTextboxes++;
        }

        //With this you will run one code if only one textbox has value and other if more than one has value
        if(filledTextboxes == 1)
        {
            switch(textBoxID)
            {
                case 1:
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    comboBox1.Items.Add("TextBox1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    comboBox1.Items.Add("TextBox2");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    comboBox1.Items.Add("TextBox3");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("All items cleared because there are {0} boxes with value", filledTextboxes));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cheers but how do i populate my comboboxes? i have tried `  case 1:
                        //Populate comboBox with Mobile value
                        cmb_PrefConNumber.Items.Add("Mobile");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //Populate comboBox with landline value
                        cmb_PrefConNumber.Items.Add("Landline");
                        break; `

Comment: filledTextboxes var is not incrementing  properly, the textboxId is populating fine but it alsways skips to else

Comment: You used `textBox1.Text` in any of the `String.IsNullOrEmpty`. You may want to fix that.

Comment: Yea it need to be 3 different textboxes

Comment: what should i change i to

Comment: Have you imported `ontextchange` events or just copied what i wrote

Comment: imported so they have all their ref to the desinger

Comment: filled textbox doesnt increment, it stays at 0 no mater what

Comment: Any idea @AleksaRistic

Comment: @RobertS. Could your ellaborate please

Comment: I meant Aleksa Ristic. There are 2 mistakes in the presented code and I just wanted to point them out.

Comment: what mistakes are they please ? is it using string.isnullOrEmpty rather than using isNullOrWhitespace

Comment: Oh i see what u meant, textboxe event handlers have the same textbox in

Comment: Yes. Exactly. :)

Comment: @RobertS. Have you any idea why my Var `filledTextboxes`  is not incrementing?

Comment: I am home now and going to test it and i will post final code

Comment: @dave.2 there was some mistake with my `?:` operator since i am not using it often so i changed it to normal if statement and i missed `!` since i need to add up `filledTextboxes` if string IS NOT null or empty. Edited code above is working and tested but i suggest you to learn debugging because it took me only one run with break point and i know where the error is so try using break points, it will save you a lot of time. If you need anything else feel free to ask

Comment: How can i update it so it also deletes if the text is deleted

Comment: Do you even logic bro? Just kidding. OnTextChange event already have check if string is not empty so we just put `else`(if it is empty) and inside it we delete element from combobox (you can delete it by index so in first textbox change index would be 0, second - 1, and third 2)